# System.NullReferenceException, Error al recorrer un datagridview en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagrid

[image: **Tengo una dll la cual realiza un análisis a mi datagridview, por lo tanto al efectuar el recorrido, en la regla2 me muestra la excepción system.NullReferenceException.**]

```
public class Semantico
{
    public string semantico(DataGridView tabla)
    {
        return regla1(tabla);
    }

    string regla1(DataGridView tabla)
    {
        string token = tabla.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), r = "";

        if (token.Equals("inicio"))

            r = regla2(tabla);
        else
            r = "No a iniciado el programa";

        return r;
    }
    string regla2(DataGridView tabla)
    {
        int uf = 0;
        string token = "", r = "";
        uf = tabla.RowCount - 1;
        token = tabla.Rows[uf].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        if (token.Equals("fin"))
            r = regla3(tabla);
        else
            r = "No a finalizado el programa";
        return r;
        // error en la lectura por system.NullReferenceException
    }
    string regla3(DataGridView tabla)
    {
        string r = "";
        int ni = 0, nf = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tabla.RowCount; i++)
        {
            if (tabla.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals("inicio"))
                ni++;
            if (tabla.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals("fin"))
                nf++;
        }
        if (ni == 1 && nf == 1)
        {
            /*regla4(tabla);*/
        }
        else
            r = "No puede iniciar o finalizar el programa doble vez";
        return r;
    }
```

Comment: Hola Jose, el grid tiene menos de 3 columnas o la 3ra columna puede estar vacía... pero cual es la duda? como detectar si esta vacía?

Comment: Hola que tal Luis, mi problemas es que realizo el conteo de los campos de el datagridview, pero al momento de pasarle el valor en string a token me marca el error mencionado. Especificamente en 
token = tabla.Rows[uf].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

Comment: El error lo que dice es que tabla.Rows[uf].Cells[1].Value es null, lo puedes validar con un if(tabla.Rows[uf].Cells[1].Value == null) //Hacer algo. Pero el problema puede ser que no se llena correctamente, el error te salta al leer porque no hay nada que leer.

Comment: pon también el html de ese grid y una captura de pantalla de como se ve el grid cuando esta lleno, para entender mejor de que estamos hablando